# How to give a different background color to three different pages

Tags: javascript

I created three simple pages to test this switch statement which is located in a separate script.js file.  When I look at the code in Chrome Developer Tools, it shows an error for the first case, there are no errors for the second and third cases.  The error is:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

The code also runs the alert("homepage") two times on the homepage and the alerts only run one time on the pages 2 and 3.  The colors change, but there's something wrong with the first case.  The link to start the test is:  http://jspractice.wink1733.com once there, I just add to the URL to go to the other pages.  Thank you for helping me -- I am new to Javascript.

```
    switch(window.location.href) 
    {
   case "http://jspractice.wink1733.com/" :
        alert("homepage");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
        break;
    case "http://jspractice.wink1733.com/pages/page2.html" :
        alert("page2");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        break;
    case "http://jspractice.wink1733.com/pages/page3.html" :
        alert("page3");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        break;
    default :
        alert("nothing there");
    };
```

Comment: do not call DOM modifying thing before DOM is ready,The error is occurring because at the time the javascript file is loaded, DOM is not created yet. make `window.onload` function and move whole code inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your page has your `<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>` added twice. Both of them will run, which is why there is an error but it also works. You should only declare the script once.

The error has to do with the fact that when your first script runs, your HTML hasn't yet been fully parsed and the DOM (Document Object Model) hasn't yet been created. So there is no `body` to `style` yet! Web browsers will read an HTML file from top to bottom and start processing it right away, so your first `script.js` goes first.

There are two ways to handle this behavior.

1. The easy way is to put your `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` element, like you have it the second time. This will ensure that the `<script>` tag is read after the contents of `<body>`. If you have a really large page though, *there is still a chance for the timing to be wrong*.
2. The proper way is to listen for the `onload` event from the browser before running your code.

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
     // your code here
   };
   ```

   `window` is the global variable that represents the browser window. The `load` event fires when the browser has finished loading the DOM from your HTML - at this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

   Assigning a function to `window.onload` will cause that function to run when said `load` event fires, so you can be sure that you can start manipulating elements on the page, since they are surely there!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the JavaScript property

```
document.body.style.background = "green";
```

Now this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Some CSS on Your `Page1.html,page2.html` and `page3.html`
Using `background-color` like

```
  background-color: #b0c4de;
```

this is simplest way to do it since you have three Different pages and it contains some different data . so easily you can put color inside `body`

or you can directly access body form your JS code

```
document.body.style.background = "Red";//Showing Red Color
```

or

```
window.onload = changecolors;
```

Hope it will work